# Flask Application wont connect when ran on Docker

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile

Blessings,

I have a simple Flask Application that I can run locally without using docker..
Once I try to run it through Docker with `Docker build/run` the flask launches but gives the following when trying to connect the web `This site can’t be reached`

## simpleflask.py

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'about': 'Hello World'}

    def post(self):
        some_json = request.get_json()
        number1 = some_json[0]['number']
        number2 = some_json[1]['number']
        _sum = number1 + number2
        return {'result': _sum}, 201


api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)
```

## main.py

```
import requests

url = 'http://0.0.0.0:5000/'
myobj = {'number': 22}
mysecobj = {'number': 11}

data = requests.post(url, json=(myobj, mysecobj))


print(data.text)
```

## Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR ./app
COPY . /app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "./simpleflask.py", "./main.py"]
```

I honestly don't know what went wrong.. I've set `host=0.0.0.0` and it still doesn't work, Help is highly appreciated..

Comment: On the docker command you still need to expose the port `docker run -p 5000:5000 -t <tag> ...`

Comment: How are you starting the container?  What URL are you trying to connect to?

Comment: @flakes, this actually worked but now im having a different issue where it takes the whole terminal and ./main.py cant run afterwards.. I know in linux you can use & to make it run in silent mode.. but I cant seem to incorporate it here

Comment: When you run the container you can pass the `-d` flag, thus the container will run in detached mode

Comment: @mini I've figured this much out :) thank you!